# face-recognition crashing after face enters frame

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

I am trying to use the face-recognition python library but when I run my program the live video is shown but it crashes as soon as I put my face into frame.
This is an example program I got from the face-recognition Github repo.

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Get a reference to webcam #0 (the default one)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Load a sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
obama_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("obama.jpg")
obama_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(obama_image)[0]

# Load a second sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
biden_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("biden.jpg")
biden_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(biden_image)[0]

# Create arrays of known face encodings and their names
known_face_encodings = [
    obama_face_encoding,
    biden_face_encoding
]
known_face_names = [
    "Barack Obama",
    "Joe Biden"
]

# Initialize some variables
face_locations = []
face_encodings = []
face_names = []
process_this_frame = True

while True:
    # Grab a single frame of video
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    # Only process every other frame of video to save time
    if process_this_frame:
        # Resize frame of video to 1/4 size for faster face recognition processing
        small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
        # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
        rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]
        # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)
        face_names = []
        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            name = "Unknown"
            # # If a match was found in known_face_encodings, just use the first one.
            # if True in matches:
            #     first_match_index = matches.index(True)
            #     name = known_face_names[first_match_index]

            # Or instead, use the known face with the smallest distance to the new face
            face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
            if matches[best_match_index]:
                name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

            face_names.append(name)

    process_this_frame = not process_this_frame

    # Display the results
    for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        # Scale back up face locations since the frame we detected in was scaled to 1/4 size
        top *= 4
        right *= 4
        bottom *= 4
        left *= 4

        # Draw a box around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Draw a label with a name below the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    # Display the resulting image
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release handle to the webcam
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I keep getting this error when I enter frame.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 55, in <module>
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_loca
  File "C:\Users\markc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages
    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landm
  File "C:\Users\markc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages
    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landm
TypeError: compute_face_descriptor(): incompatible function arguments. The foll
    1. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rowjitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector
    2. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(row
    3. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rowm_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors
    4. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.nl_object_detections], num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pyb
    5. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.nd11.vectors
```

I have tried this out on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu but I get the same error.

These are the versions of the libraries I have installed.
dlib==19.24.1
face-recognition==1.3.0
face-recognition-models==0.3.0
numpy==1.24.2
opencv-python==4.7.0.72

Comment: welcome. [mre]. run your code in a debugger or at least inspect the variables at the time of the crash in any other way.